# Wordpress and Codeignitier URL conflict?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

My root path looks like this:

```
public_html
  account
    wp-load.php //and other wp files
  application 
    model 
    view 
    controller
  system
  assets
```

And inside wordpress i set that site url is root and inside root .htaccess wordpress rewrite. So i have url conflict between wordpress and codeignitier where wordpress wins. 
Inside CI controller i have some classes what i need to use, as Historic for example. So when i run

> mysite.com/historic/getcsv

it redirects me to wordpress and say Not Found.

How i can solve this?

My .htaccess is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^LoginTut.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|table-images|js|robots\.txt|css|captcha)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /account/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /account/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Inside root index.php what is index.php for CI i have:

```
require_once 'account/wp-blog-header.php';

define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        }
        else
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
    break;

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
 * Include the path if the folder is not in the same directory
 * as this file.
 */
    $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * folder than the default one you can set its name here. The folder
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server. If
 * you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
 * http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $application_folder = 'application';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * VIEW FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want to move the view folder out of the application
 * folder set the path to the folder here. The folder can be renamed
 * and relocated anywhere on your server. If blank, it will default
 * to the standard location inside your application folder. If you
 * do move this, use the full server path to this folder.
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $view_folder = '';


/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here. For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT: If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller. Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" folder.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-folder within the "controllers" folder
    // $routing['directory'] = '';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  mycontroller
    // $routing['controller'] = '';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    // $routing['function'] = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 */
    // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = $_temp.'/';
    }
    else
    {
        // Ensure there's a trailing slash
        $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';
    }

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // Path to the system folder
    define('BASEPATH', str_replace('\\', '/', $system_path));

    // Path to the front controller (this file)
    define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/');

    // Name of the "system folder"
    define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));

    // The path to the "application" folder
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $application_folder = $_temp;
        }

        define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
            echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
            exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
        }

        define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }

    // The path to the "views" folder
    if ( ! is_dir($view_folder))
    {
        if ( ! empty($view_folder) && is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
        {
            $view_folder = APPPATH.$view_folder;
        }
        elseif ( ! is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
            echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
            exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
        }
        else
        {
            $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
        }
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $view_folder = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    else
    {
        $view_folder = rtrim($view_folder, '/\\').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder);

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```